# Overriding function with Sinon.mock?

Tags: node.js, mocking, sinon

The document says

> var expectation = mock.expects("method");
>   Overrides obj.method with a mock function and returns it. See expectations below.

What's the syntax for that?

I tried

```
var mock = sandbox.mock(myObj).expects(myObj, "myfunc", function(){
                console.log('please!!!')
            }).once();
```

and

```
    var mock = sandbox.mock(myObj).expects("myfunc", function(){
                console.log('please!!!')
            }).once();
```

But neither of them work.

Answer (score 7):

Nitpick: you named your variable `mock`, but `expects()` returns an expectation.

In any case, [Sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks) says that `mock()` takes a single argument and returns a mock object.  `expects()` returns an expectation, which is both a spy and a stub, so you could do something like this:

`var mock = sinon.mock(myObj).expects('myfunc').returns('something');`

If you wanted to replace `myObj.myfunc` with a custom function, you could use a stub, perhaps like this:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(myObj, 'myfunc', function() {
    console.log('something');
});
```

**For Sinon version >= 3.0.0**

```
var stub = sinon.stub(myObj, 'myfunc')
stub.callsFake(() => { 
  console.log('here')
  return Promise.resolve(1)
})
```

Comment: This has been replaced with `sinon.stub(obj, 'meth').callsFake(fn)` since version 3.0.0

Comment: @AdonesPitogo I had a quick question. How do you use this method(callsFake) if 'meth' function has arguments too?

Comment: @SameerSrivastava`sinon.stub(obj, 'method').callsFake(function(arg1, arg2) { /* do what you want with args here */ })`

Comment: no, this did not working. I keep getting the same response